# another user can login without existing user logout

Tags: php, html, css, session

When I leave my page by pressing back button. The login page should not come. Because I am already logged in! How can another user login when some other user is already logged in! It should ask the existing user to logout and then allow another user to login! Example: when we log in Facebook, and try to go to the login page. It doesn't open the login page, instead it opens up our account, because we are still logged in!

account page code:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
?>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="content">
logged in
</div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
}
else
{
header('location:login.php');
die();
}
?>
```

register code:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['REGISTER']))
{
$user=$_POST['user'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,email_id,password) VALUES ('$user','$email','$pass');";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_id='".$email."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
echo "OOPS! This email id is already registered.";
  header ("refresh7; url=login.php");
}
else
{
if($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)
{
echo 'Hello'.' '.$user.'!'.'<br>';
}}}
$conn->close();
header ("refresh:7; url=login.php");
?>
```

login page code:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="left">
<h2> <a href="login.php"> <center> LOGIN </center> </a> </h2>

<form action="" method="post">

<b> Email Id: </b> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" required> <br> <br>
<b> Password: </b> <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="****" required> <br> <br>

<input type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="LOGIN">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])==true)
{
echo '<font color="red"> <p align="center"> username & password does not match! </p> </font>';
}
?>

</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['LOGIN']))
{
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_id='$email' AND password='$pass'");

$row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

if($row>0)
{
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
header('location: account.php');
}
else
{
header('location:login.php?error=1');
}}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries. Passwords also should be hashed.

Comment: Every page must start the session and every page must check `$_SESSION['id']` to know if a login has already been performed

Comment: @Confiqure pls don't forget to remove snippet formatting from non-runnable code when editing

Answer (score 1):

You could add some sort of session validation,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
     ?>

     Your Logout HTML

     <?php
} else {
    ?>
    Your Login HTML.
    <?php
}
```

The `if` statement will show the logout `HTML` when your `ID` session is set, which will only be set when you login.

The `else` part will show the login `HTML` when the `ID` session is NOT set hence you aren't logged in.

Instead of having to include it on every page, you could simply split you website in to sections, for example header, content and footer and include this code in your header then in your main file just use `require` or `include` to save you the trouble of having to write the whole part out again.

**Edit**

You are prone to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)'s or [PDO's](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)'s [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: i have added it on my accounts page!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your login page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
   header("Location:account.php");}
```

You'll need more authentication though. This will make sure the user is redirected to the account page if he tries to view the login page.

Comment: Glad it did @tanishas you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: i have encountered a new problem by adding the above code segment on top of my login page! Before on entering wrong email or password, a message was echoed saying 'inavlid email/passwrd'. But now, it doesnt echo anything on entering wrong credentials, and just refreshes login page!

Comment: It's because you're depending upon a GET request to show your error messages. And your entire code is flawed and prone to many attacks.  @tanishas

Comment: how can i make it more secure?? i am new to php that is why i have used simple coding to build this up!

Comment: I can assist you in securing it if you want. @tanishas